# is it possible to connect a zoom h1 to nagra 4.2 to digitze reels?

Tags: nagra

Hello,
Does anyone have experience here?  I know that i can connect to the nagra with a bannana to 1/4 adapter...but will the quality suffer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the quality will suffer, when they're digital atleast you can readily access them.
But there isn't a true line level input on the Zoom H1 so you may find you clip, try lowering the level on the H1 first considerably gage it from there where you'll need to be 6db 12db etc/.
The H1 is a great little unit, nice and light, durable (abs plastic) which makes sense no moving parts so it doesn't need to be metal, the X/Y mics are nice and handy and I've dropped mine half a dozen times and it works flawlessly and I can't see where it hit.
But if you haven't yet bought it then I'd pay a little more for the Sony PCM-M10 which does have a true pro line level input so what you get out of the Nagra you're going to capture correctly

Answer (score 1):

I ended up (after much research) having my friend build a pad that provides 26.7 decibels of attenuation.  The Nagra output is much too hot for the zoom... so "internet human" maybe you shouldn't be snarky unless you know what you are talking about?  @Internet   Oh and transferring to the zoom (that I am "stuck with") works perfectly now.

Comment: ditto for hiding behind a pseudonym

Answer (score -1):

The "quality suffering" is not really something to be worried about in line level signals (or audio transferred at line level over short distances). Besides, if you're stuck with having only a H1, then there aren't any options for "better A/D conversion" etc.